# Partition Function Breakdown

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $g(n,k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts, in which no part is a $1$. Show that
$$g(n,k) = g(n-2,k-1) + g(n-k,k).$$

How would I show this?

Comment: You would *think* about the problem.  You would understand how the two terms on the right contribute all the solutions on the left and do not double count.